# approved app with in-app purchase not working

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, itunes-store

I've developed an app, submitted to the AppStore and just recently was approved.

The issue is that the app (now approved and downloaded from the store) isn't getting the products and therefore is crashing.

Is this expected to happen?

Should I wait some more time or did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait 24 hours and if it is still not working, but it worked before, then something is obviously not matching up. By the way, your app is **NOT** supposed to crash when it can't find any products. There are similar threads to this on Stack Overflow, so I'd look those up, too, along with Googling stuff.